# How to connect to production (remote) database via any desktop application?

Tags: database, ftp, database-connection

I have my production online website with MySql database.
How can I connect to that database via desktop application like sqlyog, Toad for Mysql etc?

Comment: Erm, FTP is for file transfers. Databases don't use FTP.

Comment: It's not clear what you need to do with FTP - copy database's backend files or what?

Comment: Sorry, I really asked stupid question adding word "FTP". I just wanna access my database tables via any desktop application. I don't want all time go to my web cpanel, I want work with my data from desktop.

Comment: Please be more specific in your questions, so we can provide better answers! :)

Comment: I've edited my question. Now it's clear enough.

Answer (score 2):

For administering MySQL databases local or remote there is Oracle's MySQL Workbench application which is free of charge. With it you can connect to one or more databases, execute queries, add remove tables, schemas, reverse engineer existing databases, create models, etc.

You can check it from here http://wb.mysql.com/ which is the official home page.

Comment: Thank you Stef. Actually I got solution, I have to connect by SSH tunneling with sqlyog, and all I need is there :)

Comment: @AlmasAdilbek: Can you answer your own question in a way that would help others? If you do, you can select yours as the correct answer. It may seem strange, but it is the preferred way of dealing with situations like this.